# Objective-C code hang

Tags: objective-c

I have a tap counter and this is the "Who Wins" code. The app is crashing whenever Flipped (int timer) is equal to 30 and it is deciding who had the most taps. It always says "Player 2 Wins" and freezes. Please help. Number is the number value of one tapper, Number1 is the value of the second tapper. How do I fix this?

```
- (void)countup 
{
    if (Fliped == 30)    
    {
        //error message 
        if (Number < Number1) 
        {
            myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Stop!" message:@"Player 2 Wins!" delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0
                                                     target:self selector:@selector(countup)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

            [myAlertView show];
        }
        if (Number > Number1) 
        {

            myAlertView = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Stop!" message:@"Player 1 Wins!" delegate:self
                                           cancelButtonTitle:@"OK" otherButtonTitles:nil, nil];
            timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:0.0
                                                     target:self selector:@selector(countup)userInfo:nil repeats:YES];

            [myAlertView show];

        }
    else
    {
        MainInt += 1;
        seconds.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", MainInt];
        Fliped += 1;
        secondsFlip.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", Fliped];
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

what could be the cause of this crash???

Comment: You're welcome!  (Did you have a question?)

Comment: I am not sure, but you might need a space between @selector(countup) and userInfo

Comment: this has nothing to do with Xcode and I would've removed the tags & word from the title myself if it hadn't been edited a few times before I could've saved my own edit ;-)

Comment: I suspect your delegate methods (which you don't show) for the alert view are at fault.

Comment: @MichaelDautermann -- (Has nothing to do with if statements either, other than they happen to be in the same program.)

Comment: Don't name variables with uppercase letters in Objective C. Every time you do, George Lucas makes a new Star Wars movie. Matt's answer is right: the timer... What were you trying to achieve with it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling your own method `countup` recursively an infinite number of times when the variable `Fliped` is 30. That's why you're crashing. Don't do that.

Comment: Thanks that worked, I created a -(void)stop which stopped the ints, and changed the @selecter to (stop)

Comment: @ch1pa that was totally the wrong thing to do. You've still created a timer that will keep on calling `stop` forever. Why are you putting a timer in there at all? If you want to stop a timer, use `invalidate` on it. If you want to call `stop` when you detect a winner, just call `[self stop]`

Comment: Thanks Tim Kemp, this worked even better than the other solutions.